# 2 обработчика для одной формы

Tags: php, javascript, html, яндекс-касса

Доброй ночи, есть форма от Яндекс кассы.

```
<form action="https://money.yandex.ru/eshop.xml" method="post">
<input name="shopId" value="xxxxxx" type="hidden" required/>
<input name="scid" value="xxxxxx" type="hidden" required/>
Введите сумму оплаты<br>
<input name="sum" value="" type="number" min="1" required><br>                                       
<!-- Поле name="customerNumber" обязательное, его нельзя удалять. По нему вы сможете понять, кто вам заплатил. Вы можете назвать это поле как угодно. Например, вместо "Имя покупателя" написать "Идентификатор плательщика", "Номер клиента", "Имя клиента" или "Номер заказа". -->
<input required name="phone customerNumber" value="" class="phone" size="64" placeholder="Ваш номер телефона"/><br>                                          
<!-- Эти поля можно убрать или переименовать.>
<input required name="custName" value="" size="64" placeholder="Имя"/><br>
<input required name="custAddr" value="" size="64" placeholder="Адрес доставки"/><br>
<input name="custEmail" value="" size="64" placeholder="Email"/><br>
<input style="margin-bottom: 5px;" type="submit" value="Купить">
</form>
```

Как сделать еще 1 обработчик, чтобы данные из формы при заполнении отправлять как из обычной формы?В данный момент форма от яндекса, отправляет данные только при успешной оплате. А нужно чтобы данные приходили сразу после нажатия кнопки купить, т.е. нужен еще 1 обработчик на форму, подскажите как реализовать можно?

Comment: Попробуй сделать 1 обработчик, который будет отсылать данные на оба обработчика.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы прикреплять несколько обработчиков на одно событие, можно использовать .on():

```
function handler1() {...}   
function handler2() {...}
$('#myForm').on('submit', handler1);
$('#myForm').on('submit', handler2);
//используйте ссылки на обработчики (handler1 и handler2) 
//, чтобы можно было в случае чего их снять
```